# Proof outline of a certain sentence (Introductory course on logic, proof writing et al.)

Tags: logic

The exercise asks me to outline a direct proof that if $\mathbf A$ is a diagonal matrix, then $\mathbf A$ is invertible whenever all its diagonal entries are nonzero.

To me this sounds like $P\implies(Q\implies R)$ where $P$ is "$\mathbf A$ is a diagonal matrix" and $Q$ is "all its diagonal entries are nonzero" and finally $R$ is "$\mathbf A$ is invertible". And as we can check in wolframalpha, we have that $$\Big\{P\implies(Q\implies R)\Big\}\iff\Big\{(P\wedge Q)\implies R\Big\}$$ is a tautology.

> Assume that $\mathbf A$ is a diagonal matrix. Furthermore assume that all its entries are nonzero.
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   Therefore $\mathbf{A}$ is *invertible*.
>   Thus, $\mathbf A$ is a diagonal matrix, then $\mathbf A$ is invertible whenever all its diagonal entries are nonzero.

Is my proof outline correct?

Comment: The logic is correct. I wouldn't call that a proof outline though. I usually would refer to the "meat" of the proof as the "proof outline". That is, what is the main idea you're going to use? The main trick? The sequence of steps? Your intuitions? Any lemmas? Edit: Of course, that's just my choice of terminology :)

Comment: Actually, at a very high level, I suppose I would concede that this is a sort of proof outline... and yes it is correct. But again, it's only really "setting up" the proof. Most of the work is yet to be done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a proof from the two premisses $P, Q$ to the conclusion $R$ is evidently also a proof from the premiss $P$ to the conclusion that if $Q$ also holds, then $R$.

So far so good. As Colm Bhandal comments, you now have the serious work left to do.

But it is rather alarming that you are appealing to Wolfram here! If you are unsure about this sort of thing, then you need to get your head round some basic informal-logic-useful-for-maths right now. Daniel Velleman's rightly much admired *How to Prove It* (CUP) is written for exactly someone with your (apparent) needs. I warmly recommend you promptly get it out of the library and work through it carefully. The time spent will be very profitable.

Comment: lol the sentence 'as we can check from wolframalpha' meant that I'm too lazy to actually check it for myself and not that actually don't know how to ;)